# Seeking Assistance with Solid State Relay and Arduino Nano Power Failure Solution

Tags: electrical-engineering, battery

This is my first time, and I'm looking for guidance on my approach to a particular problem: ensuring that a Solid State Relay (SSR) closes whenever my Arduino Nano loses power. The SSR, powered by the Arduino Nano's 5V pin, is designed to activate a bulb either during specific trigger events (as programmed in the Arduino) or when the AC-DC adapter, powering Arduino Nano, wall socket loses power.

To maintain power to the SSR in the event of an Arduino power failure, I have set up a backup system using 3 AA batteries. The challenge is to create a circuit that switches to battery power only when the Arduino is unable to supply power. My current design utilizes 2 Schottky diodes. However, to prevent current leakage (which is dangerous to non-rechargeable AA batteries), I have used a P-channel MOSFET to block reverse current flow.

Here is the circuit diagram for reference:

[image: Circuit Diagram]

And here is the link to datasheet of OMRON G3MB-202P (1565E) that is used in SSR module that I would be using: [G3MB.pdf (digikey.com)](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Omron%20PDFs/G3MB.pdf).

I am seeking assistance with the following:

1. Confirmation that this circuit effectively prevents backflow current when the Arduino's power supply is active.
2. Assurance that the battery will not drain while the Arduino's power source is dominant.
3. Verification that the circuit switches to the battery source within an acceptable delay (less than 0.5 seconds) when the Arduino loses power.
   4.Guidance on connecting the SSR (which is low trigger so needs to be grounded to activate) to one of the digital pins on the Arduino Nano, especially considering the common ground shared when the battery source is used.

I apologize for the following:

- The circuit diagram is not complete; additional resistors are needed
  to prevent short-circuiting. The image is meant to convey the basic
  principle rather than a detailed schematic.
- The relay channel pin control circuit is not connected, as I am uncertain about this
  aspect.
- I have used the symbol for a Zener diode instead of a
  Schottky diode, and the SSR symbol is not accurate due to limitations
  in the diagramming tool I used.
- Instead of a traditional schematic, I
  have provided an image for ease of creation.
- I have posted this query
  on multiple platforms to reach a broader audience and gather diverse
  insights.

I greatly appreciate any help or advice on this project.

Thank you in advance!

Regards,

Prabhas K.

Comment: Have you considered the option of a rechargable battery that you can float at VCC through a diode? That way you don't have to worry so much about backfeeding the batteries, because that's then an intentional part of the design.

Comment: @ratchet I'm unfamiliar with creating an AA battery charger circuit. If anyone can help me design a circuit to use a rechargeable battery that recharges while there is power and then powers the SSR when power is lost, I would definitely use it

Comment: This Q is better for the EE stack - https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: also FYI that looks like a flip-flop symbol

Comment: @Pete yes it does seem to be flip-flop

Answer (score 0):

To your questions- the principle using the diodes is fine. Just make sure there is at least ~300mV *more* actual voltage coming from the 5V line than the battery.

Here's a circuit using the elements you have maybe a little more effectively.
R1 = is a pull-up, 33k or whatever, keeps M1 normally off when there is 5V power, and normally on when there is not 5V power. The MCU's output pin can activate it with inverse logic, i.e. pin=0V turns it on.

In the 5V-power-off-condition, D3 may be necessary to provide a path for R1 to pull down to approx 0V, i.e. a de-powered power rail, just in case the 5V pin on the Ardu Nano tristates when the thing is off (you have to check the datasheet).

R2 then should be sized to establish the required current into the SSR to guarantee it turns on plus a little safety margin. When reckoning that, take into account minimum operating value of Vbat (ie less than 4.5V), V drop from diode D2, and V drop from the LED in the SSR (per that datasheet).

[image]